# Lower semi-continuity of conditional mutual information

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, information-theory

We know that mutual information $I(X;Y)$ is lower semi-continuous of the joint distribution $F(x,y)$. What can we say about $I(X;Y|Z)$ once $Z$ has a finite alphabet?
Thanks

Comment: I got the answer. Yes, in this case, the conditional mutual information is also lower semi-continuous.